# How to use buyerPostalCode itemFilter param with npm's node-ebay module

Tags: node.js, ebay-api

I am using [npm's ebay module](https://github.com/ttezel/node-ebay) to make a request to Ebay's api for items that meet a certain criteria, chiefly, their keyword and their distance from a zip code. I want to use Ebay's api [ItemFilterType](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/types/ItemFilterType.html) in order to set the `MaxDistance`, which is one of the filter types and about which the docs state

> "Specifies the maximum distance from the specified postal code
>   (buyerPostalCode) to search for items. The request must also specify
>   buyerPostalCode."

I am setting the params, as the `ebay` module states, only I've tried adding the itemFilterTYPE AND MaxDistance filters, but it is not working. How can I add the itemFilterType parameter to my call so that it will filter out items not within a certain zip code?

I was trying something like the following:

```
var params = {
  'OPERATION-NAME': 'findItemsByKeywords',
  'keywords': 'shoes',
  'itemFilter': 'MaxDistance',    
  'buyerPostalCode': 94506
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching modules to [ebay-api](https://github.com/benbuckman/nodejs-ebay-api), which is slightly different from the previous module I was using, but more consistent with the ebay api documentation.

You tell ebay the buyerPostalCode (zip code) like so:

```
var params = {};

params.keywords = [ 'Harry Potter stuff' ];
params.buyerPostalCode = ['94101'];
```

In order to set the filters, and specifically `MaxDistance` you do the following:

```
filters.itemFilter = [
  new ebay.ItemFilter("FreeShippingOnly", false),
  new ebay.ItemFilter('MaxDistance','5'),
  new ebay.ItemFilter('MinPrice','10'),
  new ebay.ItemFilter('MaxPrice','55')
];
```

You can make your request as follows (This is [straight from the docs example](https://github.com/benbuckman/nodejs-ebay-api/blob/master/examples/paginated.js)):

```
ebay.paginateGetRequest({
    serviceName: 'FindingService',
    opType: 'findItemsAdvanced',
    appId: '......................',      // FILL IN YOUR OWN APP KEY, GET ONE HERE: https://publisher.ebaypartnernetwork.com/PublisherToolsAPI
    params: params,
    filters: filters,
    pages: pages,
    perPage: perPage,
    parser: ebay.parseItemsFromResponse
  },
  // gets all the items together in a merged array
  function allItemsCallback(error, items) {
    if (error) throw error;

    console.log('Found', items.length, 'items from', pages, 'pages');

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      console.log(items[i]);
    }  
  }
);
```